# How do I merge bracketed files together into an HDR image on a Mac?

Tags: software, hdr, macintosh, bracketing

I'm looking for software in order to put files from bracketing together under Lion and create HDR image.

Comment: You used the HDR tag, so I am going to assume that you want to "put them together" as to create an HDR image.

Comment: exactly. sorry for not being clear

Comment: @Pablo: you can edit the question and title to be more clear.

Comment: @Pablo: Just out of curiosity, is Adobe Photoshop not sufficient? It has a pretty decent HDR merge feature built right in, so if you already have Photoshop (not sure if you do), you already have a tool. Photoshop is also readily available on MacOS.

Comment: @jrista: costly, for non-profit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software I like best currently for HDR merging on the Mac is Nik HDR EFX Pro.  It has a number of different ways you can vary the merge and so far has some of the more realistic tone adjustment I have seen.

http://www.niksoftware.com/hdrefexpro/usa/entry.php

They have an Aperture/Lightroom and Photoshop plugin.

Comment: I tried Nik HDR EFX Pro and the results are pretty exciting. Wondering if I can use it within LR...

Comment: Yes, I think the Aperture plugin is also a LR plugin.  You should be able to download a demote to try out.

Comment: +1 for Nik HDR Efex Pro
works with (as plugin) Adobe Photoshop, Bridge, Lightroom and Apple Aperture (http://www.niksoftware.com/hdrefexpro/en/entry.php?view=de/features.html#multi_app_plugin)

Comment: @el_migu_el The link to Nik Software is no longer valid 

Answer (score 2):

I am not MAC user, but under Windows I used opensource [Luminance HDR](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/?page_id=10) and as I see, it is also available for MAC, so you can try it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use Lightroom on a Mac to do most of my usual processing, so I opted for the [LR/Enfuse plugin](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrenfuse.php).

It is a "donationware" product, so the price is up to you, and the tool itself works wonderfully, and integrates extremely well into the Lightroom workflow.

Prior to my switch to Lightroom, I used [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/), which is open source, and also uses [enfuse](http://wiki.panotools.org/Enfuse) from the panotools project under the covers to do the processing.

Comment: I tried Hugin, but seems it can not work with RAW files, only jpeg?

Comment: Right, not RAW, but it can handle tiff, so you can avoid lossy compression.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at HDRtist and [HDRtist Pro](http://www.ohanaware.com/hdrtistpro/). They are both easy to use programs that on the easier to use side, with adjustment sliders for controlling the HDR effect(s).